# Cannot renew Hashicorp Vault token generate by LDAP user login

Tags: authentication, ldap, consul, hashicorp-vault

I have a Vault server backed by a Consul cluster and  integrated with my LDAP server, it works fine with my LDAP server and every thing goes well with it, but the only thing is I cannot renew the tokens generated by these logins.

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behaviour:

1. Run `vault login -method=ldap username=myusername -renewable=true` and get the token as following:

```
Password (will be hidden):                                                        
Success! You are now authenticated. The token information displayed below         
is already stored in the token helper. You do NOT need to run "vault login"       
again. Future Vault requests will automatically use this token.                   


Key                    Value                                                      
---                    -----                                                      
token                  s.wCQedkMmX61EJszE64HqPzhC                                 
token_accessor         qcxkggK00WxgwmxOC9Ht9vpc                                   
token_duration         24h                                                        
token_renewable        true                                                       
token_policies         ["default"]                                                
identity_policies      []                                                         
policies               ["default"]                                                
token_meta_username    myusername
```

2. Login as `root` user and Run `vault token lookup s.wCQedkMmX61EJszE64HqPzhC` to check token status and ttl:

```
Key                 Value                                    
---                 -----                                    
accessor            qcxkggK00WxgwmxOC9Ht9vpc                 
creation_time       1576051650                               
creation_ttl        24h                                      
display_name        ldap-myusername                    
entity_id           1fc1f68d-face-f9f1-468f-36b94e10fb3b     
expire_time         2019-12-12T08:07:30.56805754Z            
explicit_max_ttl    0s                                       
id                  s.wCQedkMmX61EJszE64HqPzhC               
issue_time          2019-12-11T08:07:30.568070919Z           
meta                map[username:myusername]           
num_uses            0                                        
orphan              true                                     
path                auth/ldap/login/myusername         
policies            [default]                                
**renewable           true**                                     
ttl                 23h55m5s                                 
type                service
```

As it is obvious the `renewable` property of the token is `true` and its `type` is `service`, so it can be renewed.

3. Run `vault token renew s.wCQedkMmX61EJszE64HqPzhC` to renew the token given above.
4. When I look up the token again nothing happened to its `ttl`. Run `vault token lookup s.wCQedkMmX61EJszE64HqPzhC`:

```
Key                 Value                                   
---                 -----                                   
accessor            qcxkggK00WxgwmxOC9Ht9vpc                
creation_time       1576051650                              
creation_ttl        24h                                     
display_name        ldap-myusername                   
entity_id           1fc1f68d-face-f9f1-468f-36b94e10fb3b    
expire_time         2019-12-12T08:07:30.56805754Z           
explicit_max_ttl    0s                                      
id                  s.wCQedkMmX61EJszE64HqPzhC              
issue_time          2019-12-11T08:07:30.568070919Z          
meta                map[username:myusername]          
num_uses            0                                       
orphan              true                                    
path                auth/ldap/login/myusername        
policies            [default]                               
renewable           true                                    
ttl                 23h53m24s                               
type                service
```

**Note:** I tried the steps above using API calls and self-renew but the result was same as above.

**Expected behavior**

My expected behaviour was after running `vault token renew s.wCQedkMmX61EJszE64HqPzhC` for a LDAP token as `root` the `ttl` of the token gets back to `creation_ttl` vaule.

**Environment:**

- Vault Server Version:

```
root@ubuntu:~# vault status                         
Key             Value                               
---             -----                               
Seal Type       shamir                              
Initialized     true                                
Sealed          false                               
Total Shares    5                                   
Threshold       3                                   
Version         1.3.0                               
Cluster Name    vault-cluster-11d62d58              
Cluster ID      a9704841-7f1c-1986-a880-a2c252f23ed2
HA Enabled      true                                
HA Cluster      https://10.1.10.1:8201          
HA Mode         active
```

- Vault CLI Version:

```
root@ubuntu:~# vault version
Vault v1.3.0
```

- Server Operating System/Architecture:
  My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 with this info:

```
root@ubuntu:~# uname -a                                                                               
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Vault server configuration file(s):

```
listener "tcp" {                           
  address          = "0.0.0.0:8200"        
  cluster_address  = "10.1.10.1:8201"  
  tls_disable      = "true"                
}                                          

storage "consul" {                         
  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"               
  path    = "vault/"                       
}                                          

ui = true                                  
api_addr = "http://10.1.10.1:8200"     
cluster_addr = "https://10.1.10.1:8201"
```

**UPDATE:**

You can use this sample free LDAP server config. to reproduce the situation:

```
#Test LDAP server
vault write auth/ldap/config \
    url="ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389" \
    userdn="uid=tesla,dc=example,dc=com" \
    userattr="uid" \
    groupattr="cn" \
    groupdn="dc=example,dc=com" \
    binddn="uid=tesla,dc=example,dc=com" \
    bindpass='password' \
    starttls=false
```

login using: `vault login -method=ldap username=tesla` and `password` as password and then try to renew the generated token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bug on version `1.3.0` of Vault, I have created an [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/8002) for the bug, which leads to a PR for the next version, and the problem got fixed on `1.3.2`.

Answer (score 1):

The `LDAP` auth backend's max `TTL` may be set at `24h`. This means that tokens generated cannot live past `24h` from its creation.

See the `TTL` by running

```
vault auth list --detailed
```

If the value is `system` the default value is `32 days` or the value specified in the Vault configuration file.

Max `TTL` can be tuned by:

```
vault mount-tune -max-lease-ttl=<NEW TTL> auth/ldap
```

Additional info [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/guides/identity/lease#step-1-read-token-auth-method-configuration)

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't get if there is any way to renew an LDAP login token or not? I changed my `max-lease-ttl` to `system` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, there is just like any other token. Try these steps: `vault mount-tune -max-lease-ttl=48h auth/ldap` (tunes the max TTL for LDAP tokens to 48 hours), then create a new LDAP token.  Wait a few seconds and renew. Try `vault token lookup` again you should see TTL extend to 24 hours.

Comment: Tried but still doesn't works! Could you please check my update at the end of the question post? tnx

Comment: I've created an issue for this purpose and the issue marked as `bug` in vault repository. So, we have to wait for `v1.4`
https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/8002

Comment: Ok great! I will follow it.

Comment: They've responded to my issue and the problem resolved, sorry for the late update. :)